# edit inline ui_component doesnt working

Tags: uicomponent, inline-editor

Help me check..
I cann't edit inline grid ui component
I dunno where I wrong? Here is my code for columns part in :

**scportal_subscriptions_subscriptions_amountused_edit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">scportal_subscriptions_subscriptions_amountused_edit.scportal_subscriptions_subscriptions_amountused_edit_data_source</item>
    </item>
</argument>
<settings>
    <buttons>
        <button class="ScPortal\Subscriptions\Block\Adminhtml\SubscriptionAmountUsed\Edit\BackButton" name="back"/>
    </buttons>
    <spinner>scportal_subscriptions_subscriptions_amountused_columns</spinner>
    <deps>
        <dep>scportal_subscriptions_subscriptions_amountused_edit.scportal_subscriptions_subscriptions_amountused_edit_data_source</dep>
    </deps>
</settings>
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    <settings>
        <sticky>true</sticky>
    </settings>
    <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
    <filters name="listing_filters"/>
    <paging name="listing_paging"/>
</listingToolbar>
<columns name="scportal_subscriptions_subscriptions_amountused_columns">
    <settings>
        <editorConfig>
            <param name="selectProvider"
                   xsi:type="string">scportal_subscriptions_subscriptions_amountused_edit.scportal_subscriptions_subscriptions_amountused_edit.scportal_subscriptions_subscriptions_amountused_columns.ids</param>
            <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
            <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">subscription_items_id</param>
            <param name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="saveUrl" path="scportal_subscriptionitems/SubscriptionItems/inlineEdit" xsi:type="url"/>
                <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </param>
        </editorConfig>
        <childDefaults>
            <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">scportal_subscriptions_subscriptions_amountused_edit.scportal_subscriptions_subscriptions_amountused_edit.scportal_subscriptions_subscriptions_amountused_columns_editor</item>
                <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                    <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </param>
        </childDefaults>
    </settings>
    <selectionsColumn name="ids">
        <settings>
            <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
            <visible>false</visible>
        </settings>
    </selectionsColumn>
    <column name="usage_unit">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <label translate="true">Usage Unit</label>
            <editor>
                <editorType>text</editorType>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
            </editor>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="is_fixed_per_tier" class="ScPortal\Subscriptions\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\IsFixedPerTier" >
        <settings>
            <filter>select</filter>
            <options>
                <option name="0" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">No</item>
                </option>
                <option name="1" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Yes</item>
                </option>
            </options>
            <label translate="true">Fixed Price Per Tier</label>
            <editor>
                <editorType>select</editorType>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
            </editor>
        </settings>
    </column>
</columns>
```